# Как уменьшить потребление памяти

Tags: python, python-3.6

Есть клиент-серверное приложение. Суть клиента отправлять на сервер свой внешний айпи адрес. В данный момент он жрет около 14 мегабайт. Подскажите, можно ли как то уменьшить этот объем?

```
import subprocess, sys, socket, time, re, datetime, http.client, random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mg
from uuid import getnode
class Client_authentication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_client = 0
    # GUI для аутентификация
    def authentication_gui(self):
        authentication = tk.Toplevel(root)
        authentication.geometry('300x130')
        x = (authentication.winfo_screenwidth() - authentication.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
        y = (authentication.winfo_screenheight() - authentication.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
        authentication.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label_authentication = tk.Label(authentication, text='Введите ключ для аутентификации:')
        self.area_authentication = tk.Entry(authentication, bd='2', width=30)
        aply_authentication = tk.Button(authentication, text="Применить ключ", command=self.authentication, width=20)
        cansel = tk.Button(authentication, text='Выход', command=root.destroy, width=20)
        label_authentication.place(x=55, y=10)
        self.area_authentication.place(x=60, y=50)
        aply_authentication.place(x=15, y=90)
        cansel.place(x=155, y=90)
        authentication.mainloop()
    # Обработка аутентификации
    def authentication(self):
        self.key_client = self.area_authentication.get()
        if self.key_client == '':
            mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Ключ пуст.')
            return
        sock.send(bytes(self.key_client, 'UTF-8'))
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode()
        if data == 'False':
            mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Ключ не верен.')
            root.destroy()
        else:
            sock.send(bytes(address, 'UTF-8'))
            mg.showinfo('Успешно', 'Добро пожаловать в наши ряды!\nПерезапустите клиент.')
            root.destroy()
    # Проверка hosts
    def check_host(self):
        reference = []
        with open('C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts', 'r') as file:
            file = file.read()
        for i in reference:
            file.rstrip()
            check = bool(file.find(i) + 1)
            if check == False:
                with open('C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('320x250')
    root.title('Client ver. 0.1a')
    # Окно по центру, в гугле нашел))
    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2.5
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2.5
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    label_info = tk.Label(root, font=6, justify='left')
    label_info.grid()
    label_info['text'] += 'Client ver. 0.1a приветствует Вас.\n'
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    client_authentication = Client_authentication()
    try:
        client_authentication.check_host()
        label_info['text'] += 'Проверили файл hosts...\n'
    except(PermissionError):
        label_info['text'] += 'Не удалось получить доступ к файлу hosts...\n'
        label_info['text'] += 'Надеемся там все верно...\n'
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ifconfig.me")
    conn.request("GET", "/ip")
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M %d-%m-%Y')
    len_pack = []
    google_dns = '8.8.8.8'
    host = '192.168.33.246'
    port = 49444
    address = str(getnode())
    ip_address = conn.getresponse().read().decode()
    ip_address_temp = ip_address
    name_client = 'Не_установлено'
    label_info['text'] += 'Проверяем интернет...\n'
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Вызов пинга для проверки инета
    inet = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", google_dns], stdout=False)
    if inet == 0:
        label_info['text'] += 'Успешно!\n'
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост 8.8.8.8 не доступен. Нет интернета.')
        sys.exit()
    label_info['text'] += 'Подключаемся к серверу...\n'
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Подключаемся в хосту и читаем что он нам передал
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((host, port))
    except(ConnectionRefusedError):
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост ' + host + ' не доступен.')
        sys.exit()
    except(TimeoutError):
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Ответ от сервера не получен. Программа завершилась по таймауту.')
        sys.exit()
    try:
        sock.send(bytes(address, 'UTF-8'))
    except(ConnectionRefusedError):
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост ' + host + ' не доступен.')
        sys.exit()
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
    except(OSError):
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Не удалось получить данные с удаленного хоста.')
        sys.exit()
    data = data.decode()
    if 'False' in data:
        client_authentication.authentication_gui()
    label_info['text'] += 'Успешно!\n'
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    label_info['text'] += 'Получаем данные от сервера...\n'
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    # Записываем в список все данные от хоста
    len_pack = re.findall('\d+', data)
    if not len_pack:
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Не удалось получить данные с удаленного хоста')
        sys.exit()
    if inet == 0:
        sock.send(bytes('Подтверждение от машины с ID ' + address + ' время ' + now + ' ' + ip_address, 'UTF-8'))
        label_info['text'] += 'Успешно!\n'
        root.update()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        label_info['text'] += 'Можно заходить в 1С.\n'
        root.update()
        label_info['text'] += 'Спасибо!\n'
        root.update()
        button_ok = tk.Button(root, text='Закрыть', command=root.destroy, width=10)
        button_ok.place(x=210, y=210)
        root.update()
    else:
        mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост 8.8.8.8 не доступен. Нет интернета.')
        sys.exit()
    sock.close()
    root.mainloop()
    # Бесконечный фоновый цикл
    while True:
        # conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("ifconfig.me")
        # conn.request("GET", "/ip")
        # ip_address = conn.getresponse().read().decode()
        now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M %d-%m-%Y')
        a = random.randint(0, 255)
        b = random.randint(0, 255)
        c = random.randint(0, 255)
        d = random.randint(0, 255)
        ip_address = str(a) + '.' + str(b) + '.' + str(c) + '.' + str(d)
        if ip_address_temp != ip_address:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            try:
                sock.connect((host, port))
            except(ConnectionRefusedError):
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост ' + host + ' не доступен.')
                sys.exit()
            except(TimeoutError):
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Ответ от сервера не получен. Программа завершилась по таймауту.')
                sys.exit()
            try:
                sock.send(bytes(address, 'UTF-8'))
            except(ConnectionRefusedError):
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост ' + host + ' не доступен.')
                sys.exit()
            try:
                data = sock.recv(1024)
            except(OSError):
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Не удалось получить данные с удаленного хоста.')
                sys.exit()
            data = data.decode()
            if 'False' in data:
                client_authentication.authentication_gui()
            # Записываем в список все данные от хоста
            len_pack = re.findall('\d+', data)
            if not len_pack:
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Не удалось получить данные с удаленного хоста')
                sys.exit()
            if inet == 0:
                sock.send(bytes('Подтверждение от машины с ID ' + address + ' время ' + now + ' ' + ip_address, 'UTF-8'))
            else:
                mg.showerror('Ошибка', 'Хост 8.8.8.8 не доступен. Нет интернета.')
                sys.exit()
            sock.close()
            time.sleep(60)`
```

Comment: Даже просто пустой питон сразу занимает 10 мегабайт, так что 14 мегабайт это очень мало и ничего уменьшать не нужно (и не получится)

Comment: Сделайте просто консольное приложение, без ткинтера.

Comment: Ок я понял вопрос снят, спасибо

Comment: не доверяй восьмеркам) наши провайдеры подменяют dns и иногда восьмерки не доступны при рабочем инете, а иногда доступны при нерабочем. редко конечно, но подставляют. Бывает сам гугл банит если много запросов идет с адреса.